# believe wholeheartedly

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Does (1) sound natural in English?

> 1. What we **believe wholeheartedly** is not necessarily the truth.
> 2. What we believe with all our hearts is not necessarily the truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Both sentences are correct.

Note that the style, especially of (1) is somewhat formal.  However that is not a problem considering the sentiment conveyed.